# Giving Null pointer exception at the invoke time of alarm which is already set in prevoius activity

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am testing simple alarm application. In firstactivity I set alarm with ringtone which is picked from  Ringtonemanger, for that I used **setRing()** method. Then through intent I passed it to Broadcast reciever,But when alarm invoked at specific time then at **player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) **  it throws **NULL pointer exception** .Anyone has idea??

```
private void setRing()
{
    intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,  RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);

    this.startActivityForResult(intent, 5);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent)
{
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 5)
    {
         Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

         if (uri != null)
         {
             this.chosenRingtone = uri.toString();
         }
         else
         {
             this.chosenRingtone = null;
         }

     }            




public class GroupsCheckAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {    

 MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer ;
 MediaPlayer player;
 Context context1;
 Uri uri=null;

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
     Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     String struri=intent.getStringExtra("uristr");
     Log.v("value of ring",struri);
     uri=Uri.parse(struri);
     context1=context;
     try {
        callringtone();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private void callringtone() throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException {
     mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
     mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context1,uri);

     final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context1.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

     if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
                player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                player.setLooping(true);
                player.prepare();
                player.start();
      }

     if(uri == null){

         uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
         if(uri== null){ 

             uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);               
         }

     }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize your `player` variable. It's null throughout the entire existence of your Broadcast receiver. So when you call `setAudioStreamType()` on it, you get your null pointer exception. You don't use the `player` variable anywhere else in your broadcast receiver, and I think you actually meant to call all those methods in your if block on mMediaPlayer. So you could solve your problem by calling all your methods on that object instead, like so:

```
 if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
  }
```

Comment: But I have another problem i.e. How to stop ringtone after 2min? I think I have to use thread for that. Is there any another way.

Comment: Pavan, I'm going to need more room that just these comments to answer that. Can you ask that in a new question?